# How to reverse the sp_hidetext command?

Tags: sql-server, sybase

It appears that it can't be done, but I really don't know why. When Sql Server executes an stored procedure it needs it's code to run it, so I'm sure that the stored procedure's code must exists in some place, but I don't know where, either.

Maybe this code is encrypted, but it could be decrypted with some tool, since the DBMS needs to do this when execute it.

So, I want to know if there is a well know place where the software stores this code (in some way or the other) and if there is a tool to extract and obtain the source code hidden by the command sp_hidetext.

Answer (score 1):

No. It's a security issue. It's stored internally in a secret way that you can't access. Only the DBMS knows how to get at it, just like a Credential has a password that is encrypted but able to be decrypted so that the password can be used when appropriate.

Comment: And since the DBMS knows how to get at it, we can too, via memory inspection. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36403702/2825369).

Answer (score 1):

From the [online sybase manual](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/refman/@ebt-link;pt=91604?target=%25N%16_107609_START_RESTART_N%25):

> **Warning!**
>
> Before executing sp_hidetext, make
>   sure you have a backup of the source
>   text. The results of executing
>   sp_hidetext are not reversible.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the process *is* reversible - the program stores comments and all. It reverses the obfuscation when the procedure is called. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36403702/2825369).

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the actual source of sp_hidetext ( with that i mean the absolute low level code that sp_hidetext is created) in order to know the algorithm for hiding the text. The best option here, is to always keep a copy of your original stored procedures as backup. I am sure this is done as part of your SDLC?

Answer (score 0):

Rob is right. Even sybase says they cant reverse the code (but I guess they can ;).

Check

```
$SYBASE/$SYBASE_ASE/scripts/installmaster
```

there you find a source code of all the procs installed in sybsystemprocs

if you follow the chain, you end up with this:

```
    /* Do hidetext stuff */
    /* ISSUE, get return value of dbcc */
    dbcc hidetext("#proc_objid_t_tab", 16)
```

..which is basically internal function with no source available (at least to you.. and me :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, and not terribly difficult.

#### Option 1: the diagnostic server

(Adapted from [this forum thread](http://www.progtown.com/topic1032948-how-to-decrypt-the-procedure-text-on-sybase-ase-157.html). I haven't tested this. I know for sure it won't work for SQL Anywhere, since it doesn't have a diagnostic mode, but allegedly it works for ASE.)

Start the server in diagnostic mode, with the `diagsrvr.exe` program. Then connect to it with some SQL tool, and run these commands (where `SECRETPROC` is the name of the hidden procedure you're interested in):

```
create table #x (id int)
insert into #x values (object_id ('SECRETPROC'))
dbcc _unhide_text ('#x')
go
```

`sp_helptext` will then work on it as normal.

#### Option 2: memory inspection

(Originally published [on my blog](http://fleexlab.blogspot.com/2016/04/reversing-sybase-sql-anywhere-set.html). I have tested this on SQL Anywhere 11. I imagine it works on similar products too.)

> To make the server load it into memory, you'll need to call it. Some installations of SQL Anywhere come with a tool labeled `dbisql.exe` that you can use as an interactive SQL environment. Invoke the procedure - it doesn't have to run; I would suggest calling it with a bogus number of arguments so that you don't accidentally run something bad. Then quickly open Task Manager, find the server process (called `dbsrv11.exe` for me because I'm using SQL Anywhere 11), right-click it, and choose *Create dump file*.
>
> Once that finishes, open the resulting file in a hex editor (though Notepad might work too). I like [XVI32](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm) for such things. Search for the name of the procedure - e.g. `SECRETPROC` - with correct capitalization. There will be a few mentions of it (and the obfuscated version of it too), keep going until you see one that starts with `create function` and has a bunch of SQL code after it. Everything from that keyphrase to the next null byte is the stored procedure's code.
>
> If you're using XVI32, click on the beginning of the interesting part in the right pane and hold Shift while using the arrow keys to go to the end of the part you want. The text will turn red. You can then use Ctrl+C to copy the data, Ctrl+N to create a new file, Ctrl+V to paste the data, and File → Save to write it out to a new file.